# How do I buy items in The Binding of Isaac?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac

Does anyone know how to buy items from the shop (or which key to use for buying)?

I keep going to the shop in the first couple of floors and it doesnt show me what to do to buy items. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 15):

You buy items by walking into them. It's just like picking up any other item, except that you automatically pay the listed cost when you pick it up. If you can't pay the cost, you just walk over the item and nothing happens.

Comment: Beware devil deals which makes you pay with HP down instead of coins. ;-)